# Select data if conditions on two separate rows are met

Tags: sql

Consider the following dataset:

```
id   dataid   data
1     3095     5
1     3096     9
1     3097     8
2     3095     4
2     3096     9 
2     3097     15
```

Now, in this, the column someid identifies to certain data, so if I see 3095, I know what data the data column represents (name, address, etc.). I need to do a check so that for the group of ids (i.e. 1 and 2) dataid=3095 then data=5 AND dataid=3096 then data=9, and if this is true, the id group will be selected and operations will be done on it.

Edit: Now I use the following SQL query to do the above:

```
SELECT *
FROM table s0
JOIN table s1 USING (dataid)
JOIN table s2 USING (dataid)
WHERE s1.dataid=359 AND s1.data=5
AND s2.dataid=360 AND s2.data=6;
```

But how can I get the output from rows to columns. The property values I need are still as key:pair values in rows and I would like them as columns.

So the output for the above would be:

```
id     3095     3096      3097
1       5        9         8
```

whereas currently it is returning from the above query:

```
id     dataid  data   dataid_1   data_1   dataid_2   data_2
1       3095    5       Unnecessary stuff because of JOIN      
1       3096    9
1       3097    8
```

Thanks and sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Could you post some sample of your desired output?

Comment: You probably want pivoting. This is done differently in different SQL products.

Comment: ODBC for the DB. For output, I am writing it out as I speak.

Comment: I am almost 99% certain what I need is pivoting now but pivoting a large DB is not feasible so first data needs to be "trimmed" by the above query.

Comment: "What db" means: Is it MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, other? If you use ODBC or other connection is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Oracle. Sorry, I am new to this DB stuff.

Comment: Ah, EAV tables, so much fun... Are the given id/dataid keys (garuanteed) unique, or are there possibly multiple rows?

Comment: The dataid keys are guaranteed unique. Didn't know these tables had a particular name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id 
      FROM table) as ids
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT '1' 
              FROM table t2 
              WHERE t2.id = ids.id AND dataid = 3095 AND data = 5) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1' 
            FROM table t2 
            WHERE t2.id = ids.id AND dataid = 3096 AND data = 9)
```

Also, if you're querying additional tables besides the given one (one with `id` as a unique key, preferrably), consider including that, to remove the need to use `DISTINCT`